# how to download issues from asf jira

Tags: json, rest, curl

I am currenly working with unstructured data. i am planning to mine the unstructured data present in bug reports.

For which i tried to download the issues from the asf jira for the project- PIG.

The issue tracker alllows me to export issues in xml,excel amd word formats. but i need json. The issue tracker throws an 403 forbidden error when i try to export in json format.

how can i do this...

1.must i use the rest api?
2.does asf jira support rest api?
3.How to formulate a curl command which uses rest and jql to accomplish the task

i tried the following and got error. What have i missed out

> curl -D -u $username:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/search?jql=project=%3DPIzG"

i am trying to download all the issue of the project -PIG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes,apache jira uses REST api verison 2, i am currently using jira-python 1.0.7(library) to access the asf jira through the REST api.

CURL command returns JSON object, but JIRA-python intreprets these JSON object and make them easily accessible through python.